# Feed Me and Assets Field - Mapping Trouble

Tags: plugin-feedme, assets-field

I'm trying to import a JSON file to map a bunch of asset paths to their appropriate related entries.  While I've followed the instructions in the docs, I'm still having trouble connecting the file path in JSON with its related Assets field.

I have the following JSON structure, with "Record Id" representing the path to the file on the server, and "Parent ID" representing a field in my section to which I can identify the correct entry to map the asset.

```
[
  {
    "Record Id": "http://reminc.info/uploads/Call Reports/9s0353ca7831970c344b6afd2949eade4bf42_Agrati Reilingen, D 20120-02-11_ss.doc",
    "Parent ID": "zcrm_4320009000001781082"
  }
]
```

I've verified that the file path maps to a file on my server, and that the "Parent ID" value matches the field within the target entry.

All this said, Feed Me is failing to import the URL to create the link to the asset.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

[image: mapping fields in Feed Me]

[image: appropriate fields as they appear in Craft]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Have you set the feed to update existing entries?
2.) Try to url-encode the URL in the JSON, it contains special chars like spaces.

Comment: 1) Yes, I should have mentioned that I'm set to update existing entries. and 2) I tried a URL without any spaces or special markup, and still no luck. This URL is only one of about 3000 in my file, and none have imported.

Comment: Matthias- I tried URL encoding the Record Id and it worked after all. Thank you!

Comment: Very happy to assist!